# What is the latest spring-data-jpa which is suitable for Java 11

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Which spring-data-jpa latest is suitable for Java 11?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I try to google it, but without success.

Comment: Ask for a specific version. The latest will change over time.

Comment: Is there somewhere on the internet list of versions per jdk? I didnt find it.

Answer (score 1):

Given [Spring Data 2022.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Spring-Data-2022.0-%28Turing%29-Release-Notes) introduced a baseline of Java 17 (the previous baseline was Java 8), you can't use the versions of libraries that are part of Spring Data 2022.0 or newer with Java 11.

Spring Data 2022.0 includes Spring Data JPA 3.0. In other words, for Java 11 support, you need a Spring Data JPA 2.7 (part of [Spring Data 2021.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Spring-Data-2021.2-%28Raj%29-Release-Notes)) or older. The latest 2.7 release of [`org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa` is 2.7.18](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/2.7.18). As far as I'm aware, there will be no new updates for 2.7, so this is also the last release for 2.7.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can find suitable version of java jpa, which fit jdk 11?

Comment: @PetrKostroun You'll need a Java Persistence / Jakarta Persistence 2.2, but not because newer versions are not compatible with Java 11, but because spring-data-jpa 2.7 and older expect the `javax.persistence` namespace, and not the `jakarta.persistence` namespace of JPA 3.0 and higher.